# Not return the web page if the user manually changes the url address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a website and it has multiple pages which a user needs to go through them step by step. for example the first page www.website.com/personal.html will ask users to fill in their personal information and then the next page www.website.com/favorite.html will ask other questions about their favorites and so on...

What I would like to do is not allowing a user to manually enter the address www.website.com/personal.html and access that page again. I would only allow accessing that page through the flow of the website or if I have a tab or a link to that address.

Is there any way to prevent such thing?

Comment: Why have them be different pages? This generally works better on a single-page site where javascript shows/hides content. I don't believe there is a way to do this with multiple pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVC, why are you talking about static html pages at all?

Just use a single action method that returns multiple views based on your workflow state.  That way, it's impossible for the user to direct based on URL (since the URL would be the same for every view).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the referer header to detect where a link came from, but that is easily forged.  Assuming you have a session database and you are setting some manner of session cookie, you could store state information with the session data, and redirect if you receive a request for personal.html if the saved state does not indicate that is the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not really.  You can check the referrer but that can easily be spoofed.  You could use a cookie to indicate that the user has already been at each step, but again, easily circumvented.

If you are saving information after each step, can't you just check if the user has already input his personal info and if so, redirect him to the next step?

The only reliable way would be to check the saved data on the server side and act based on that.